# How to concatenate rows in one field in oracle, with a query over mutliple tables

Tags: oracle, join, listagg

this is in an oracle database.  thus the use of listagg....

I have a customer table and an assets table.  I need to be able to return the IP addresses in the asset table separated by commas.  there can be 2 to 30 (or so) IPs per customer.

**Assets**

```
cust_id   IP
ABCD      192.168.1.5
ABCD      192.168.1.6
ABCD      192.168.1.7
DEFG      192.168.10.1
DEFG      192.168.10.2
```

**Customers**

```
Cust_id    Cust_name
DEFG       My first customer
ABCD       My second Customer
```

I need to return this:

```
My First Customer    DEFG    192.168.10.1, 192.168.10.2
My second customer   ABCD    192.168.1.5, 192.168.1.6, 192.168.1.7
```

a simple join query works perfectly fine to return the individual rows:

```
select  
CUST_NAMES.CUST_ID as CUST_ID, CUST_NAMES.CUST_NAME, IP
 from CUST_NAMES
INNER JOIN ASSETS 
ON CUST_NAMES.CUST_ID = ASSETS.CUST_ID
```

listagg works beautifully on a single table query:

```
select ASSETS.CUST_ID, listagg(IP, ',') within group (order by ASSETS.CUST_ID) 
from ASSETS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
ON CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID = ASSETS.CUST_ID
group by ASSETS.CUST_ID
```

But, when I try to add the customer name to my query it tells me it's not a GROUP BY function

```
select CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME, ASSETS.CUST_ID, listagg(IP, ',') within group (order by ASSETS.CUST_ID)
from ASSETS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
ON CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID = ASSETS.CUST_ID
group by ASSETS.CUST_ID
```

Comment: @Alex, .... I hope you heard the **SLAP** on my forehead .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All non-aggregate columns in the select list have to be included in the `group by` clause, so you need to add `CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME` to that too.

```
select CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME, ASSETS.CUST_ID,
  listagg(IP, ',') within group (order by ASSETS.CUST_ID)
from ASSETS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
ON CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID = ASSETS.CUST_ID
group by CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME, ASSETS.CUST_ID
```

It isn't really anything to do with two tables being involved.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one customer (name) per customer ID (I guess), I see no reason for not simply adding CUST_NAME to your GROUP BY:

```
select CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME, ASSETS.CUST_ID, listagg(IP, ',') within group (order by ASSETS.CUST_ID)
 from ASSETS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID = ASSETS.CUST_ID
group by ASSETS.CUST_ID, CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME
```